# A linked list program using one class

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, linked-list

Is it possible to write this single linked list program in the class Node and using all methods of class LinkedList inside that by eliminating the class LinkedList and using only one class for all this ? If it is possible then why we prefer writing this way and why not with a single class ?
Some say we use it to keep a track of head node but I don't get it. We can simply use a head named variable to store the head node and then use it further in other operations. Then why a different class for head node.

```
class Node:  

    def __init__(self, data):  
        self.data = data  
        self.next = None
  
class LinkedList:  
    
    def __init__(self):  
        self.head = None
  
    def push(self, new_data):  
        new_node = Node(new_data)  
        new_node.next = self.head  
        self.head = new_node  
 
    def deleteNode(self, key):  
          
        temp = self.head  
        if (temp is not None):  
            if (temp.data == key):  
                self.head = temp.next
                temp = None
                return
 
        while(temp is not None):  
            if temp.data == key:  
                break
            prev = temp  
            temp = temp.next
  
        if(temp == None):  
            return
  
        prev.next = temp.next
        temp = None
  
    def printList(self):  
        temp = self.head  
        while(temp):  
            print (" %d" %(temp.data)),  
            temp = temp.next
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Presumably people find it clearer to distinguish between a linked list and a node in the linked list.

Comment: Your method.  I have a linked list and I pass it to a function.  That function deletes the first element and then returns.  The caller is now hanging onto a disconnected element, rather than the  linked list itself.

It's a cleaner design to separate the object itself (a linked list) from the things that are part of the implementation of the object.

Comment: Likewise, in your scheme, what is an empty linked list?  None?  How do I call methods on it?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots and lots of ways to implement the same interface as this `LinkedList` class.

One of those ways would be to give the `LinkedList` class `data` and `next` fields, where `next` points to a linked list...  but why do you think that is better?  The `Node` class in your example is only used inside a `LinkedList`.  It has no external purpose at all.  The author of this LinkedList class made two classes so he could separate the operations applied to nodes from the operations applied to the list as a whole, because that's how he liked to think about it.  Whether you think your way is better or worse is a matter of choice...

But here's the real reason why it's better to keep `LinkedList` separate from nodes:

In real life programming, you will encounter many singly-linked lists.  Probably *none* of these will be instances of any kind of `List` class.  You will just have a bunch of objects that are linked together by some kind of `next` pointer.  You will essentially have only nodes.  You will want to perform list operations on those linked nodes *without* adding list methods to them, because those node objects will have their own distinct purposes -- they are not meant to be lists, and you will not want to make them lists.

So this `LinkedList` class you have above is *teaching* you how to perform those list operations on linked objects.  You will *never* write this class in real life, but you will use these techniques many many times.

Comment: I got you somewhat 60 % . But still could you give me any example to have a better view of the differences between using Linkedlist class or Not.